# How to display google map inside ng-if div in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am displaying a Google Map inside an Angular (and Ionic) app.

I have the following div in the view that is intended to show the map only if it is true. When I run this, I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null". I'm confused because the map div should be showing because it's parent div should evaluate to true. But for some reason, it's not displaying.

Any adviceo on how to display the map only when map_display = 'true'?

```
<div ng-if="map_display == 'true'">
  <div id = "map" data-tap-disabled="true" style = "height:{{heightWidth}}px;"></div>
</div>
```

My controller has:

```
$scope.map_display = 'true';

$scope.initialise = function() {
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.758446, -122.411789);
          var markersArray = [];

          //Initial settings for the map
          var mapOptions = {
                  center: myLatlng,
                  zoom: 2,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                  styles: [{ featureType: "poi", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]}]

              };

          //Load the initial map
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); 

          //Event listener to add a marker      
          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            clearOverlays();
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
            $scope.coordinates = e.latLng;
            localStorage.userLat = $scope.coordinates.lat();
            localStorage.userLong = $scope.coordinates.lng();
          });

          //Actual function to add a marker
          function placeMarker(position, map) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: position,
              map: map
            });
            map.panTo(position);
            markersArray.push(marker);
          }

          function clearOverlays() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
              markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markersArray.length = 0;
          }

          // $scope.map=map;

    };
    // End of initialise

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

> Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

usually occurs when the map div is not being rendered on page when initialization function is invoked.

In your case it is most likely is related with line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());
```

Try to replace it with:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initialise);
```

> Also note `google.maps.event.addDomListener` function accepts for
>   third parameter a function callback, so the proper syntax is
>   `$scope.initialise`

**Working example**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MapCtrl', [
    '$scope',

function ($scope) {

    $scope.map_display = 'true';

  
    $scope.initMap = function () {

        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.870501, 151.206704);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initMap);
}]);
```

```css
 #map-canvas {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
            <div ng-if="map_display == 'true'">
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you changed `$scope.initialise()` to `$scope.initialise` ?